# This code should print i=1 but it is printing i=0 Why is it so?

Tags: c

```
#include<studio.h>
int main()
{
   int a=5,i;
   i!=a>10;
   printf("i=%d",i);
   return 0;
}
```

This code should print i=1 but it is printing i=0  Why is it so?

Comment: Those are three completely different languages, only tag the relevant one. Also, this is clearly not copy-pasted, given `<studio.h>`.

Comment: `i` is used uninitialized. Do you know what `!=` is?

Comment: You want to turn up your compiler warnings and change the statement `i = !(a > 10);`

Comment: *should return i=1 but it is printing i=0* - it returns 0, there is no variable in the return statement. Also, `return` and `print` are two different things which don't depend on each other.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.  Fix warnings. ???  Profit.

Comment: What do you think `i!=a>10;` does?

Comment: You say `i` should be set to 1, but I don't see any code that sets `i` to anything.  What code is it that you believe sets `i` to 1, and why?

Comment: C is a hard enough language as it is.  If your compiler doesn't warn you about problems like `i!=a>10`, learning C will be even harder than that.  If at all possible, you really do need to figure out how to increase your compiler's warning level, or find a better compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't do anything to i.
Your "i!=a>10" evaluates to false, but the result is not stored into a variable.
As it is mentioned in the comments, you need something like this:

```
int a = 5;
int i = !(a > 10);
```

The != is mostly used in if-clauses, like

```
if (a != 0) {...}
```

I hope this helps. ;)

Comment: C has a lot of compound assignment operators — `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `&=`, `|=`, `^=`, `<<=` and `>>=`.  But the operators `<=`, `>=` and `!=` are not assignment operators — they are relational or equality operators.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not printing because:

- the variable `i` is not initialized
- the second statement should be changed and be a variable `int i = !(a > 10)`

Returning a value and printing it are *different* things, but that's not the point of the question.